# Can I pour a thin concrete slab in my crawl space to prevent rodent intrusion?

Tags: foundation, pest-control

Unfortunately I have a rather persistent rat problem in my crawlspace and I still haven't been able to resolve it.

I'm considering if it would be possible to pour a thin layer of concrete to stop rodent intrusion.

Can this be done for an existing crawlspace? I'm assuming the crawlspace vents would need to be knocked out and the concrete piped in. House is about 1k sqft.

Comment: Of course it's possible. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had that problem when I moved in. The back part of my house has a crawl space where rats easily chewed holes in the siding. I replaced the bottom 2 feet of siding with metal lath on 2x4 framing and plastered it with cement mortar. I dug it below grade so they couldn't get under it. It looks like concrete, even though the plaster/lath is only 1/2" thick. Just to be sure, I poured a 3" concrete walkway around the outside perimeter. The materials were cheap, and no more rats.

That fix is over 20 years old. You can see the gray caulk joint between the foundation and crawlspace is the only sign of deterioration. I put 1" foam between the 2x4 framing behind the metal lath to make it easier to plaster (keeps the plaster from pushing through the metal lath.

[image: rat-proof plaster & metal lath]